# How can I specify a height on my image, let it scale naturally. Then draw it perfectly with canvas with pure JS

Tags: javascript

So I am attempting to make a meme generator. I am using canvas, and am trying to set my memes to be at a height of 300px. However I want the width to keep the same ratio so that the image still looks normal. If I use image.width it gives me 0 for some reason. After I get the width I need to set my canvas to be that same width. What would be the easiest way to do this. I appreciate you guys in advance!

I tried to resize the image by adjusting the height, it keeps it's width.
I tried to use the canvas 5 argument function, I don't even know what that did.
I have console.logged width after my image is loaded, and it says it is 0.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to create a canvas with a height of 300px, automatic width and the image that fills all the space. It's correct?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.